# Is quap from R in python?

Tags: r, bayesian, python, posterior

I'm looking for the `quap` (quadratic approximation posterior distribution) function which is implemented in `rethinking` package in R (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rethinking/versions/2.00/topics/quap) in Python. Is it implemented somewhere or is there an analogous function in Python? 
Thanks.

Edit:
In Pystan, I have not found it in the `optimizing` as @Demetri Pananos suggested (doc here https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pystan/model.html#StanModel.optimizing).

Comment: I *think* this performs Maximum A Posteriori.  Stan and pystan should be able to do this via the `optimizing` function.

Comment: agreed with @DemetriPananos just look at the quap function, it calls optimising with hessian on..), however, there might be a port of rethinking to python

Comment: I have found this two, that's what you mean?
https://canyon289.github.io/pages/InferenceCheatsheet.html#Quadratic-(Laplace)-Approximation and
https://github.com/pymc-devs/resources/blob/master/Rethinking/Chp_02.ipynb? I have not found it in pystan.